# How to use Try and Catch with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, try-catch

I want when the two arguments of function sum are numbers, the code success, but when one of the two arguments is not a number I want to throw an exception.

```
  const sum = (num1: number, num2: number) => {
    return num1 + num2;
  };

  try {
    typeof sum(8, 'A') === 'number';
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('the type you entered is NaN');
  }
```

Now as a Test I put a string value instead num2 but the code ran without showing the exception in the console
I mean it didn't log that 'the type you entered is NaN' from the catch block

```
catch (e) {
    console.log('the type you entered is NaN');
  }
```

I want to log that in console when arguments are not numbers, How to make that?

Comment: I would've thought this sort of error would be picked up in the *compiler* - isn't typescript supposed to be strictly typed?

Comment: Typescript won't let you write `sum(8, 'A')`, because you explicitely wrote that both arguments must be numbers. Your application just won't compile. You won't even reach the point where it gets executed and can throw an error in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just throw a new error:

```
  const sum = (num1: number, num2: number) => {
    return num1 + num2;
  };

  try {
    if (typeof sum(8, 'A') !== 'number'){
      throw new Error('the type you entered is NaN')
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

Comment: 1. Don't use exceptions as flow control. 2. This code *shouldn't compile*. The error should be completely irrelevant when using TS.

Comment: if you replace 8, 'A' with user input variable TS will not give you any error. It could be better to manage a cast to number error, but it's a different question.

Comment: A user input variable would *most likely* be of type `string`. `prompt` returns `string | null` for example. If you're reading it from standard input, it should still be a string. The only way to pass a string is to *deliberately* bypass the type system and use `any` which is ***not a good practice at all***. If you are ignoring the type system, then of course you won't get compilation error for type mismatches. My suggestion here is to use TS correctly instead of incorrectly. Then you won't have problems.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript would not throw exceptions in runtime, it compiles into native javascript. It can only show your mistakes with types and throw errors during compilation.
If you want to catch an exception you can use `throw new Error('/*error text*/')`